# i want to display database value without loop

Tags: codeigniter

i have selected data from data base in my model. now i have passed that array to the view now i want to display the value with for each loop. this is my controller code.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
    $this->load->model('content_cms');
    $data['rec']=$this->content_cms->getAll();
    $this->load->view('index',$data);

}
function about(){

    $this->load->view('about');

}}?>
```

i can display the whole array through loop in my view but is there any way to display one recode because i want to display records in different places in my view page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just then use something like this in your view:

```
<?php foreach ($rec as $thing1): ?>
    Username: <?=$thing1->username;?>
    Password:  <?=$thing1->password;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then somewhere else on the page, you can just use another foreach

```
<?php foreach ($rec as $thing2): ?>
    Favourite colour: <?=$thing2->fav_colour;?>
    Favourite smell: <?=$thing2->fav_smell;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: sir basically i have a table and have home, about,contact, entries now i want to display it in navigation

Answer (score 0):

To get a single record out of your array you will have to know the array key, for example:

```
var_dump($rec[0]);
```

This is very unreliable though and won;t recommend doing it, alternatively you could change they array keys to something that isn't likely to change. So before you send the data to your view you can do something like this:

```
foreach($this->content_cms->getAll() as $rec) {
    $data['rec'][$rec->slug] = $rec;
}
```

Then in your view you can call it individually by doing:

```
var_dump($rec['my-post']);
```

Hope this helps, good luck!